# Only selected cells are visible in datagrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I'm currently encountering a problem regarding viewing a data in  datagrid. I was able to display it in datagridview but the problem is the data are invisible. It only becomes visible when selected.

Here's the output display:

[image]

[image]

I just want to know what command can i add to my code in order to make it visible. Thanks. Here's my code:

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class ProfessorList
    Private Sub ProfessorList_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dgvView()
    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvView()
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb;")
            conn.Open()
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * from ProfessorListTable", conn)
            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(dt)
            dgvProfessorList.DataSource = dt
            addDGV()
            adapter.Dispose()
            command.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Sub addDGV()
        With dgvProfessorList
            .Columns(0).Width = 100
            .Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns(1).Width = 150
            .Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
            .Columns(2).Width = 150
            .Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
            .Columns(3).Width = 40
            .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
            .Columns(4).Width = 100
            .Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
            .Columns(5).Width = 110
            .Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFilter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFilter.Click
        Try
            Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb;")
                conn.Open()
                Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM ProfessorListTable "
                Dim where As String = ""
                If rbEngineering.Checked Then where &= " Department = 'Engineering' AND"
                If rbArchitecture.Checked Then where &= " Department = 'Architecture' AND"
                If rbTechnology.Checked Then where &= " Department = 'Technology' AND"
                If where <> "" Then query &= "WHERE" & where
                query = query.Substring(0, Len(query) - 3)

                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
                Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
                adapter.Fill(dt)
                dgvProfessorList.DataSource = dt
                addDGV()
                adapter.Dispose()
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        Catch
            MsgBox("Please select Department to filter!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnProfile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnProfile.Click
        With Profile
            .lblIDnum.Text = dgvProfessorList.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
            .lblFirstName.Text = dgvProfessorList.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
            .lblInitial.Text = dgvProfessorList.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
            .lblLastName.Text = dgvProfessorList.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
            .lblDept.Text = dgvProfessorList.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value
            .lblYearEmployed.Text = dgvProfessorList.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value
            .ShowDialog()
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you change the back color of your datagridView.. check you data gridview property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the DataGridViewCells don't have a style applied where the ForeColor is the same as the BackColor.

Check the DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle property.

Cheers

Comment: What a mistake. Thanks a lot! :)